# factory pattern android

Tags: android

How to design factory pattern in android.I write down my approaches with a sample.kindly guide with corrections?

```
/*Interface*/  
public interface ViewShape {
    void setViewShapeColor(int color);
}

/*View Class*/
public class CircleView extends View implements ViewShape{
private Paint paint;

@Override
public void setViewShapeColor(int selectedColor) {
    this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
    invalidate();
}}
 /*Factory class*/
public class ViewFactory {
    public static ViewShape getView(Context context, String shapeType) {
        if ("circle".equalsIgnoreCase(shapeType)) {
            return new CircleView(context);
        }
    }
```

From the main activity, I can get the view by using

```
ViewShape viewShape = ViewFactory.getView(this, "circle");
```

but cannot set `setContentView(viewShape);`

Answer (score 0):

google says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern . The idea is that that factory is used when you have to create different families of objects. Alternatively, consider 'factory method' pattern - if you need just one kind of object